# can't connect teradata from sql clr code

Tags: .net, sql-server, teradata, sqlclr

I try to create SQLCLR proc that access teradata server and I get this error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: LoadFrom(), LoadFile(), Load(byte[]) and LoadModule() have been disabled by the host.

I google about this error and I found that I need to create `<dllname>.XmlSerializers.dll` and add this to the DB. I did that and still I get same error.

The code work stably with Oracle and SQL Server, but I can't add Teradata.

I'm using `Teradata.Client.Provider` namespace from the assembly `Teradata.Client.Provider`.

The server version is 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 solutions.

1. I replaced `Teradata.Client.Provider` with `System.Data.Odbc`, etc. i use odbc connection and it's fine.
2. I create exe file that perform the code and my clr code only run the exe file and join to him. The disadvantage in this that i can't use `context connection=true` in my code.